# Getting data from mongodb collection trough the console of a web browser

Tags: mongodb, security, meteor

I am following the official meteor.js tutorial:

https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/collections

Why can I get the data from the collection through the browser? Can I get from the console also to: `imports/api/tasks.js`?

Comment: If you do want the data from the browser console add window.Tasks = Tasks below where the Tasks collection is declared i.e. export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');

Comment: I was asking about the security issue here. Maybe it's not an issue because I don't know much about Meteor.js

Comment: @Steve is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

> Why can I get the data from the collection through the browser?

Meteor uses a publish / subscribe system, which allows you to synchronize documents from server to the client in a straight-forward and controllable way.

Read more at: https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html

It also makes it very easy for you to handle these documents using a single definition of your Mongo Collection that can be used on the server, as well as on the client.

Under the hood it will use a custom lightweight client-side implementation of a Mongo Collection to imitate the behavior (in 99% of all cases you will not perceive any differences here).

More to read here: https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#mongo-collections

Regarding your security issue, you can define the way of how documents are synchronized to the client in the publication [by the Mongo Cursor you return](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#publications) and depending on the query and projection you use for it.

The nicest feature is, that this publication/subscription automatically updates the documents that are synced with the client if new documents are inserted or updated or removed **as long as the math the criteria in the query / projection of your publication**.

So the security is up to you and how you manage your data: https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#publications